# Why is `appendChild()` giving me issues?

Tags: javascript, html

H~ I have a script that I've been working on which will, ultimately, display Pascal's Triangle. I developed this from scratch with JavaScript, and I want to display it in the DOM.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this script produces a different effect in the DOM than it does in a console. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
 
 Copyright (c) 2015 Peter Gray Ward

 function randomScripts(){

          var arr1 = ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'];
          var arr2 = ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'];
          var n = 0;
          var len = 35;
          var mid = Math.floor(len/2)
          var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
          var home = document.getElementById("home");

          function first(){

            for(var j = 1; j<=10; j++){
              var o = j%2 !== 0;
              var e = j%2 === 0

            if(o){
              for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                odd = i%2 !== 0;
                if(j === 1){
                  arr1.splice(i,1,"_")
                }
                if(odd && (i === mid + n || i === mid - n)){
                  arr1.splice(i,1,1);
                }
                var node = document.createTextNode(arr1.join(''));
              }

              console.log(arr1.join(''));
              destination.appendChild(node);
              home.appendChild(node);
              //destination.appendChild("Please see Console for full version b/c of hackers");
            }

            else if(e){
              for(var h = 0; h<len; h++){
                even = h%2 === 0;
                if(even && (h === mid + n || h === mid - n)){
                  arr2.splice(h,1,n);
                }
              }
              console.log(arr2.join(''));
            }

            n++;

            }


          }
```

```html
 <p id="destination"></p>
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle for this. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I moved it to a snippet. But your right it doesn't work at all. I tried to add a `onclick`-Event to the p element to trigger randomScripts() but it won't start.

Comment: you have a missing bracket and you never call your function first(), you never call randomScripts() and you don't have an element with id home. Please post full code

Answer (score 0):

You created functions, but you never call them. Try actually calling them to see what they do:

```js
function randomScripts(){

  var arr1 = ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'];
  var arr2 = ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'];
  var n = 0;
  var len = 35;
  var mid = Math.floor(len/2)
  var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
  var home = document.getElementById("home");

  first();

  function first(){

    for(var j = 1; j<=10; j++){
      var o = j%2 !== 0;
      var e = j%2 === 0

    if(o){
      for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
        odd = i%2 !== 0;
        if(j === 1){
          arr1.splice(i,1,"_")
        }
        if(odd && (i === mid + n || i === mid - n)){
          arr1.splice(i,1,1);
        }

        var node = document.createElement('p');
        node.textContent = arr1.join('');
      }

      console.log(arr1.join(''));
      destination.appendChild(node);
      home.appendChild(node);
      destination.innerHTML = "Please see Console for full version b/c of hackers";
    }

    else if(e){
      for(var h = 0; h<len; h++){
        even = h%2 === 0;
        if(even && (h === mid + n || h === mid - n)){
          arr2.splice(h,1,n);
        }
      }
      console.log(arr2.join(''));
    }

    n++;

    }


  }
}
  
window.addEventListener('load', randomScripts, false);
```

```html
<p id="destination"></p>
<div id="home"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems in the script, but here are a couple I noticed. First:

```
destination.appendChild(node);
home.appendChild(node);
```

You can't append the same node in two different places in the DOM. It will remove the first one when you append it the second time. You could either create a second text node the same way you created the first, or clone the node.

Also, these two lines of code come after the `if(o)` statement body, but the `node` variable is created *inside* that if body. In the general case, you wouldn't expect this to work always, because `node` would be `undefined` if the if body were not executed. In your specific code, that won't happen because `o` is `true` the first time through the loop. But `node` only gets updated on every second pass through the loop. Is that what you want?

One last thing, the indentation is not consistent, making it hard to see what is nested inside what. It's important to use correct and consistent indentation. (And I would suggest 4 spaces instead of 2 to make it easier for people to read.)